# Testing. Checking every part of script (if block code) for correctness

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a script. How can I make it enter every if the statement, regardless of the input, to check if it works correctly?

Comment: That... doesn't sound like it'd actually ensure anything is running correctly. A program would be *expected* to go nuts and break horribly if every single `if` branch was taken.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is **unit testing**. What you are trying to achieve is **code coverage**.

To write unit testing you may look at [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html). To calculate code coverage you may look at [Coverage.py](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/)

---

If you want to go even further you can do some [fuzzing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzing), you may read this [article](https://alexgaynor.net/2015/apr/13/introduction-to-fuzzing-in-python-with-afl/) for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the `if` statements in a while loop. It depends on what the statements are checking to be true, but if it were numbers, you could use the code below

```
i = 0
while i < 3 :
    if i == 0:
        #run code
        print('statement 0 works')
        i+=1
    if i == 1:
        #run code
        print('statement 1 works')
        i+=1
    if i == 2:
        #run code
        print('statement 2 works')
        i+=1
```